# How to super the button type="submit" in a form in base module odoo 12?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, odoo-12

xml file

```
<template id="auth_signup.signup" name="Sign up login">
            <t t-call="web.login_layout">
                <form class="oe_signup_form" role="form" method="post" t-if="not message">
                  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>

                    <t t-call="auth_signup.fields">
                        <t t-set="only_passwords" t-value="bool(token and not invalid_token)"/>
                    </t>

                    <p class="alert alert-danger" t-if="error" role="alert">
                        <t t-esc="error"/>
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" t-att-value="redirect"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" t-att-value="token"/>
                    <div class="text-center oe_login_buttons pt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Sign up</button>
                        <a t-attf-href="/web/login?{{ keep_query() }}" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" role="button">Already have an account?</a>
                        <div class="o_login_auth"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </t>
        </template>
```

What im trying to do is i need to super the form submit into my custom module and i need to create a record in model A with the login data that user provide while they enter the login datas and sign up.
Please feel free to ask if my explanation is unclear.Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [web_auth_signup](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py#L29) method and get login data from `kw` dict.

```py
from odoo.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main import AuthSignupHome


class CustomAuthSignupHome(AuthSignupHome):

    @http.route('/web/signup', type='http', auth='public', website=True, sitemap=False)
    def web_auth_signup(self, *args, **kw):
        response = super(CustomAuthSignupHome, self).web_auth_signup(*args, **kw)
        
        # {'login': 'user', 'name': 'User', 'password': 'aL=5&A3#C"H([Sdr', 'confirm_password': 'aL=5&A3#C"H([Sdr', 'redirect': '', 'token': ''}

        return response
```